Constructing a projection with specific properties in a von neumann algebra with no minimal projections
Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a von Neumann algebra with no minimal projections, and let $\rho$ be a faithful normal semifinite trace on $\mathcal{M}$. Consider a $\rho$-preserving $^*$-homomorphism $\alpha : \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$.
Let $q \in \mathcal{M}$ be a projection with $0 < \rho(q) < \infty$. We seek to construct a projection $p \in \mathcal{M}$ such that:
$$
0 < \rho(p) < \infty \quad \text{and} \quad q \wedge \alpha(p) \neq 0.
$$
Attempt at Contradiction:
Now, suppose that for all projections $p \in \mathcal{M}$ with $0 < \rho(p) < \infty$, we have $q \wedge \alpha(p) = 0$. We know that for any projection $p$, we can decompose $\alpha(p)$ as:
$$
\alpha(p) = (q \wedge \alpha(p)) + ((1-q) \wedge \alpha(p)).
$$
By the assumption that $q \wedge \alpha(p) = 0$, we then have:
$$
\alpha(p) = (1 - q) \wedge \alpha(p).
$$
This implies that $\alpha(p) \leq 1 - q$ for all projections $p \in \mathcal{M}$ with $0 < \rho(p) < \infty$.
Goal: We would like to derive a contradiction from the assumption that $\alpha(p) \leq 1 - q$ for all such projection $p$. To do this, we seek to leverage the assumption that $\mathcal M$ has no minimal projections.
I know that if we assume $\alpha$ to be surjective, the problem becomes trivial, as we can always find a projection $p \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $q = \alpha(p)$. However, in my case, $\alpha$ is not surjective, and I intend to use the condition of no minimal projections in $\mathcal{M}$ to prove the result.
Can you help me complete the proof or find the contradiction from this setup?

It should be pointed out that $\alpha(p) = (q \wedge \alpha(p)) + ((1-q) \wedge \alpha(p))$ is false. That only works if $\alpha(p)$ commutes with $q$.

@DavidGao Sir is there any way to write $\alpha(p)$ as sum of orthogonal projections as above using $q$ and $1-q$?

No, there isn’t.

Given a $*$-homomorphism $\alpha: \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$ such that $\alpha(1) = 1 - q$. Then $\alpha(p)\wedge q=0$ for all projections $p\in \mathcal M.$

The final fact is wrong. You seem to be asserting that, if $p \wedge q \neq 0$ and $p = \sum_i p_i$, then there is some $p_i$ such that $p_i \wedge q \neq 0$. But this is false even in $2$-by-$2$ matrices. (Just take $p_1$ and $p_2$ be two different rank-one projections, and $q$ be a rank-one projection in the span of $p_1$ and $p_2$, but distinct from both of them.) Even if you change this to $p_i$ being an increasing net whose limit is $p$, this is still wrong. Just take $q$ to be a rank-one projection outside the algebraic span of $p_i$ but in the closed span of $p_i$, say.

@DavidGao Thank you for pointing out, but just one thing given that $\mathcal{M}$ has no minimal projections, how can rank-one projections still exist in $\mathcal{M}$?

I’m not saying there are rank-one projections in the $\mathcal{M}$ in the OP’s question. That’s, of course, not possible. I’m just saying the claimed general fact you seemed to be using is wrong, and using rank-one projections is just the easiest way to state counterexamples. (But if you want counterexamples that can appear in a von Neumann algebra with no minimal projections, even one with a faithful normal semifinite trace, as in the OP’s question, then just tensor everything with a II$_1$ factor.)

@DavidGao Thank you for the explanation. Also I have deleted my final fact.

@DavidGao Is there any insight to be gained if we assume that $\alpha$ is unital, meaning $\alpha(1) = 1$? Could this assumption provide any clues or ideas for solving the problem?

@abcdmath I was assuming $\alpha$ to be unital from the start. I didn’t see a way to prove this. I will say, though, that I don’t think $\mathcal{M}$ having no minimal projection is really relevant. The most important fact is probably that $\alpha$ is $\rho$-preserving. There are actually counterexamples without that assumption.
